# Google Sites gadget disapears on Chrome when using BACK button

Tags: iframe, google-gadget

The section which is in between the horizontal navigation bar and the "Schedule" in  [this site](http://www.abva.org) is built as a Google gadget.

When I navigate through pages of this site on Chrome and use the Chrome's BACK button to come back to the home page, the gadget completely disappears most of the time. The same thing happens with the FORWARD button as well.

When I inspect the DOM tree when the issue is active, I see that the iframe element of the gadget is there but its DOM object (html section) is null. If I reload the iframe or refresh the page, the gadget appears.

The gadget is hosted in Github [here](https://github.com/abvasvmc/abvasvmc.github.io) (abva.xml file).

This site works perfectly fine on all other browsers. I have been fighting with this for many days with no avail. I am pretty new to Gadget development. I will truly appreciate if someone could help me resolve this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved when an HtmlBox gadget with a div in it was inserted before my gadget. I made the div empty and set its width and height to zero so that it wouldn't make any visual impact. I don't have a logical explanation for this solution though.